# ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code sscanf

Tags: c

I'm getting a strange error attempting to compile my unit test code,. For some reason the compiler treats my `sscanf` call as a mixed declaration? I don't quite understand, here is the entire error:

```
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
/home/brlcad/brlcad/src/libbn/tests/bn_complex.c: In function 'main':
/home/brlcad/brlcad/src/libbn/tests/bn_complex.c:53: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
make[2]: *** [src/libbn/tests/CMakeFiles/tester_bn_complex.dir/bn_complex.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/libbn/tests/CMakeFiles/tester_bn_complex.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double expRe1, expIm2, expSqRe1, expSqIm2;
    double actRe1, actIm2, actSqRe1, actSqIm2;
    actRe1 = actIm2 = actSqRe1 = actSqIm2 =
    expRe1 = expIm2 = expSqRe1 = expSqIm2 = 0.0;
    bn_complex_t com1,com2; //a struct that holds two doubles
    if(argc < 5)
        bu_exit(1, "ERROR: Invalid parameters[%s]\n", argv[0]);

    sscanf(argv[1], "%lf,%lf", &com1.re, &com1.im); /* Error is HERE */
    sscanf(argv[2], "%lf,%lf", &com2.re, &com2.im);
    sscanf(argv[3], "%lf,%lf", &expRe1, &expIm2);
    sscanf(argv[4], "%lf,%lf", &expSqRe1, &expSqIm2);

    test_div(com1, com2, &actRe1, &actIm2);
    test_sqrt(com1,com2, &actSqRe1, &actSqIm2);

    if((fabs(actRe1 - expRe1) < 0.00001) || (fabs(actIm2 - expIm2) < 0.00001)){
        printf("Division failed...\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if((fabs(actSqRe1 - expSqRe1) < 0.00001) || (fabs(actSqIm2 - expSqIm2) < 0.00001)){
        printf("Square roots failed...\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not "a mixed declaration"; the code is mixing declarations and code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C90, all declarations must come at the beginning of a block. Put this:

```
bn_complex_t com1,com2; //a struct that holds two doubles
```

above these statements:

```
actRe1 = actIm2 = actSqRe1 = actSqIm2 =
expRe1 = expIm2 = expSqRe1 = expSqIm2 = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 3):

C90 requires all declarations to precede all statements within a block.

C99 (like C++) permits declarations and statements to be mixed.

You have an assignment statement:

```
actRe1 = actIm2 = actSqRe1 = actSqIm2 =
expRe1 = expIm2 = expSqRe1 = expSqIm2 = 0.0;
```

followed by a declaration:

```
bn_complex_t com1,com2;
```

(It shouldn't be complaining about the `sscanf` calls; check the line number in the error message against your source file.)

You can either rearrange the code, or modify your `Makefile` so it invokes the compiler in C99 mode. You appear to be using gcc; use `-std=c99` (or `-std=gnu99` if you want GNU-specific extensions. (The details of how to do this depend on how your `Makefile` is written.)

**Or** you can replace the assignments with initializers (which don't count as statements).

Personally, I prefer to have each declaration on a single line. I'd change this:

```
double expRe1, expIm2, expSqRe1, expSqIm2;
double actRe1, actIm2, actSqRe1, actSqIm2;
actRe1 = actIm2 = actSqRe1 = actSqIm2 =
expRe1 = expIm2 = expSqRe1 = expSqIm2 = 0.0;
```

to this:

```
double expRe1   = 0.0;
double expIm2   = 0.0;
double expSqRe1 = 0.0;
double expSqIm2 = 0.0;

double actRe1   = 0.0;
double actIm2   = 0.0;
double actSqRe1 = 0.0;
double actSqIm2 = 0.0;
```

But if you prefer a more compact layout, you can write:

```
double expRe1 = 0.0, expIm2 = 0.0, expSqRe1 = 0.0, expSqIm2 = 0.0;
double actRe1 = 0.0, actIm2 = 0.0, actSqRe1 = 0.0, actSqIm2 = 0.0;
```

You still need an initializer for each variable, even if you declare multiple variables on a single line.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the error is located there by the compiler but C90 requires that all variable declarations be at the top of the block so the `bn_complex_t`s are at fault.